# How do I sharpen video strips in Blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I see the Gaussian blur among others, but no sharpening filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no sharpen strip effect in the VSE (although you might be able to build one with blur).

The only solution currently is to load the strip media as a node in another scene and apply the sharpen filter node there.

Then use that scene as a source replacement for your VSE strip.

Comment: That must be why I cannot find it. Thanks for the info. It's a strange  omission, but I'm not complaining - Blender is a wonderful video editor, and if I have to run a strip through ffmpeg to sharpen it first, then I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use copies of your source footage to derive a sharpen effect.

I suggest making the source media into a meta strip so that you can replace the media as required. Duplicate the metastrip then select the top one. Add a blur to the metastrip, increase blur to 10, the more you increase the greater the sharpen effect. Add a Hue strip modifier and reduce saturation to 0.
Add another blur effect to the last and add a strip modifier Curve. Swap the curve slope so that it inverts the image. Add a Hue strip modifier and reduce saturation to 0. Set this strip's blend type to Subtract.

[image: invert blur]

Select all 3 strips and use Ctrl G to meta strip them together.
Change this new metastrip to blend type Subtract.

As long as they all stay in sync the sharpen effect will work without ghosted edges.

[image: sharpen]

For a more pronounced effect increase blur value or increase the top metastrip's Multiply value by more than 1.

[image: enhanced blur]

Comment: This solution only works for Blender 2.79 and below.

Answer (score 0):

OR...A noobs easy alternative to using Blender to Sharpen: Finish your video rendering in Blender and save.

Open the file in the latest version of VLC Media Player. Click on "View" and check "Advanced Controls".

Now Click on "Tools" and "Effects and Filters". Click on "Video Effects" and Check the "Image Adjust" Box and "Sharpen" box.

Adjust to your requirements and click on "Save".

Now click on the Play button and then very quickly on the Record button just above it.

When your clip concludes, the recording will stop and be stored in your Videos folder.

The original clip will remain in its folder as well.

Open a second session of VLC and Playback your new Sharpened video next to the original.

Evaluate your results.

If you want to adjust further, it is probably best to work with the original and make another copy, rather than rework the VLC recording a second time.

NOTE: This solution comes from someone with an astronomically large amount of experience with Blender (35  minutes) and with VLC (previously used only to play videos), so if this solution is full of holes, you might as well not explain it to me as I probably wouldn't understand you anyway. But for any application where some small degradation in resolution makes no difference, you can perform the above and will probably be happy. I was.